# Designing odoo report on an image template

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8, qweb

I have a report template which is an image, I want to create my report on this image (to obtain the specific design of the company), is there any optimised way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you explain it better? Where is the image, in the database or it is physically stored in the static folder?

Comment: it is physically stored in the static folder, my problem, is to put my fields in their convinient places on that image(which a background).
this is an example of what I want:
I have this image http://theunionstation.org/wp-content/uploads/pavers-form-final-1.jpg
And I want to fill the fields on it.

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/help-1/question/background-image-working-in-html-report-but-not-in-pdf-report-54125)?

Comment: It's not the same problem of me, I can show images on pdf, but the text isn't at the same paces as the html, is is decaled.

Comment: You mean that the text size is smaller? Can you show us a picture of your problem?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that wkhtmltopdf cannot render all the attributes you wrote in the template. Can you show us the template as well?

Answer (score 2):

You want a image as report background, so we can try like this. In Qweb report at page tag we can give background image with appropiate sytles and in row section we can define the content which will come on top of the image.

```
<div class="page" t-attf-style="background-image:url('/web/static/src/files/images/headers/image.jpg');background-size:1200px 900px; width:1200px; height:900px;">
   <div class="row" >
....... your code
.......
   </div>
<div>
```

Comment: I tried that, the issue is: when I generate the pdf, the text will loose its supposed place (decalage).

Comment: for your text, use css like position: absolute/relative, top, left, right, bottom etc, it will move the text whereever we want